# Number of triple of sequences

Tags: combinatorics

I was thinking about the following problem:

There is a set [n], and $l>0$.
How many different triples $(s_1, s_2, s_3)$ there are with following properties:

1. $s_1, s_2$ and $s_3$ are sequences all with lenght $l$ over [n] such that at each position any number from [n] can be chosen (so, for $l = 4$, and n =4, $s_1 = 1,1,2,3 $ is one such sequence, some elements from [n] might be unselected).
2. considering $s_i, 1\leq i \leq 3 $ as the sets, no letters exist in common for all $s_i,$ i.e, $$\bigcap_{i=1}^3 s_i = \emptyset.$$

I solved the problem with $s_1$ and $s_2$ by using formula of inclusion-exclusion. I am wondering if there are som other principle of solving this problem with the number of three sequences and try to use it here the same, but I stucked in hard derivations.

Thanks for any help!

PS. I am also interesting in a general problem: when there are $m$ sequences. There are some principle of solving such things considering these problems as the table problems. If someone is familiar with  literature (or some papers) which can be of help, please share me the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would  appear that inclusion-exclusion  is the best  approach here,
with  nodes $P\subseteq  [n]$  of the  poset  being used  representing
configurations  where  the elements  of  $P$  are  common to  all  $m$
sequences, plus possibly additional values from $[n]$. With $p=|P|$ we
get

$$\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p 
(l! [z^l] (\exp(z)-1)^p \exp(z)^{n-p})^m$$

Here we have used the labeled combinatorial class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SEQ}_{=p}(\textsc{SET}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))
\textsc{SEQ}_{=n-p}(\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

which         also        appeared         at        this         [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752170/),   which   is
very similar to the present question.

For the inner term we find using basically the same computation

$$l!\times p!\times [z^l] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^p}{p!} \exp(z)^{n-p}
\\ = l!\times p!\times \sum_{q=0}^l 
[z^q] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^p}{p!} [z^{l-q}] \exp(z)^{n-p}
\\ = l!\times p!\times \sum_{q=p}^l 
[z^q] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^p}{p!} [z^{l-q}] \exp(z)^{n-p}
\\ = l!\times p!\times \sum_{q=p}^l 
\frac{1}{q!} {q\brace p} \frac{(n-p)^{l-q}}{(l-q)!}$$

We thus obtain the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p 
\left(p! \sum_{q=p}^l 
{l\choose q} {q\brace p} (n-p)^{l-q}\right)^m.}$$

There is  also some Maple  code to consult  where this formula  may be
verified by enumeration.

```
with(combinat);

ENUM :=
proc(n, l, m)
option remember;
local count, recurse;

    count := 0;

    recurse :=
    proc(sofar, mult, pos)
    local part, psize, vset, mset, multnxt;

        if pos > m then
            if `intersect`(op(sofar)) = {} then
                count := count + mult;
            fi;

            return;
        fi;

        part := firstpart(l);

        while type(part, `list`) do
            psize := nops(part);

            if n >= psize  then
                mset := convert(part, `multiset`);

                vset := firstcomb(n, psize);

                multnxt := mult*l!/mul(q!, q in part)
                *psize!/mul(q[2]!, q in mset);

                while type(vset, `set`) do
                    recurse([op(sofar), vset],
                            multnxt, pos+1);
                    vset := nextcomb(vset, n);
                od;
            fi;

            part := nextpart(part);
        od;
    end;


    recurse([], 1, 1);

    count;
end;


X := (n, l, m) ->
add(binomial(n,p)*(-1)^p
    *(p! * add(binomial(l, q) * stirling2(q, p)
               * (n-p)^(l-q), q=p..l))^m,
    p=0..n);
```

Comment: Sorry! I introduce a mistake in the point 1 - ``some elements'' from [n] can be unused in constructing sequences. I am not familiar with these notations. What are the labeled combinatorial classes and $\mathcal{Z} $?

Comment: The linked-to post has documentation.